How to feel about the absurdly high invalidation rate in the US?
Hello I am an inventor with two granted US patents.
My first was infringed but it was unenforceable because the infringer was not established enough of a company to make a good target for litigation finance.
My second is now starting to be infringed and I began licensing discussions this morning with the company.
My concern is that as soon as they realize how valuable my patent is they will rush to invalidate it.
The real problem is that invalidation in the US has a success rate of 80%
But here's how Ive thought about it - every year in the US there are tens of thousands of licensing deals reached yet only one thousand invalidations. That would imply that the two are not independant and that patents are only brought to PTAB if they are bad if they are not bad they are not brought to trial. Also many are killed due to 101/Alice.
Am I thinking about this the right way?
I dont want to invest my energies on a fruitless pursuit.

"invalidation in the US has a success rate of 80%" means nothing when taken out of its context. My own feeling is a large part of the problem is that examination is hardly thorough and masses of bad patents get through.

Yes I agree - but Im trying to better contextualize it so its not as scary
